# MySQL - need better solution for query, extrem load time

Tags: php, mysql

I've got 2 tables -> apartments and availabilities.

In table apartments there are all informations about a apartment. In table availabilities there are all informations about the availability for a apartment for the next 365 days.

**Table apartments:**

```
id, name
```

Example:

```
1, Apartment 1
2, Apartment 2
```

**Table availabilities:**

```
id, apartment_id, date, status
```

Example:

```
1, 1, 2017-06-01, free
2, 1, 2017-06-02, booked
3, 1, 2017-06-03, free
4, 1, 2017-06-04, free
5, 1, 2017-06-05, free
...
6, 2, 2017-06-05, free
7, 2, 2017-06-05, free
8, 2, 2017-06-05, free
9, 2, 2017-06-05, booked
10, 2, 2017-06-05, free
...
```

Now i want search free apartments for a week in a multiple date range like:

```
SELECT apartments where id in (
    SELECT apartment_id 
    FROM availabilities 
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT apartment_id 
        FROM availabilities as a 
        WHERE availabilities.apartment_id = a.apartment_id 
        AND date >= "2017-06-01" 
        AND date < "2017-06-08" 
        AND status = "free" 
        GROUP BY apartment_id 
        HAVING COUNT(apartment_id) = DATEDIFF("2017-06-08", "2017-06-01")) 
    OR EXISTS (
        SELECT apartment_id 
        FROM availabilities as a 
        WHERE availabilities.apartment_id = a.apartment_id 
        AND date >= "2017-06-02" 
        AND date < "2017-06-09" 
        AND status = "free" 
        GROUP BY apartment_id HAVING COUNT(apartment_id) = DATEDIFF("2017-06-09", "2017-06-02"))`
```

This should lookup for all possibilities for a week in a date range (2017-06-01 - 2017-06-30)

My problem here is, we got many apartments and this query has a extreme load time.

Any ideas for a better solution?

Comment: Can you do `DESCRIBE {Table_name}` and `EXPLAIN {Your_Long_SQL_QUERY}` and `SHOW INDEX FROM {Table_name}` and  post results?

Comment: How many `OR EXISTS` parts will come... (28?) because the main query is not closed with this syntax? After `01 - 08` and `02 - 09` will there more ?? Because of `2017-06-01 - 2017-06-30`

Comment: Results of descripe and explain can i post tomorrow @Dimi

Comment: yes @JustOnUnderMillions there are more exists parts for the whole range

Comment: I would do `get all rows where date between 2017-06-01 - 2017-06-30 and free` and then do the rest in php. That you have an table for each day is hard! (Lets say 10.000+ objects becomes 356*10000 entries) And the  thing is that you get `apartment_id`s but how do you know witch date range/period was matched. Last note: can you reduce via arrival/departure days?

Comment: In the first step I don't need to know which period was matched. This is what i do in a second step with mysql and php. And isn't it faster to filter the free range in mysql then php? Any other ideas to handle free status for the next 365 days @JustOnUnderMillions ? Serialize the data for every object and search dates in this was much heavier

Comment: _And isn't it faster to filter the free range in mysql then php?_ Depends on the table structure and 20+ subquerys in one sql arent that nice. It can be done better, but not explained here in a comment. If i got more maybe i will post an answer.

Comment: Would be nice. I will post structure tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with (COUNT(*) and filter for status = "booked") = 0

Query is 30% faster.